# Remove empty cells from array (Bloomberg edition)

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I am having some problems getting my code to work exactly as intended. currently my output looks as below:

```
x1  x2  x3       x5        x4
v1  v2  v3       v5        v4
```

while i want the output to look like this:

```
x1  x2  x3  x5  x4
v1  v2  v3  v5  v4
```

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Sheets("EUR").Range("AF44:AG193").Copy
Range("AL44:AM193").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("EUR").Range("AL8:AL17").Copy
Range("AM8:AM17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("EUR").Range("AP41:BD42").ClearContents


   
    ' create wrapper object
    Set b = New BCOM_wrapper
    '
    ' create securities vector
    'determine length
    Dim x As Long
    x = 14

    'redim vector s to length and fill
    ReDim s(0 To x)
    For x = 1 To UBound(s) + 1
            s(x - 1) = Cells(42 + x, 1)
    Next x
    
    
    ' create fields vector
    
    Dim y As Long
    y = 1
    
    Do While Cells(39, y + 1) <> ""
    y = y + 1
    Loop
    
    ReDim f(0 To y - 2)
    For y = 1 To UBound(f) + 1
            f(y - 1) = Cells(39, 1 + y)
    Next y
    '
    ' retrieve result from wrapper into array and print
    r = b.referenceData(s, f)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For j = 0 To UBound(r, 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(r, 2)
            Cells(i + 41, j + 42) = r(j, i)
        Next i
    Next j

    ' release wrapper object
    Set b = Nothing

    End Sub
```

The basic idea is to have these columns to be sorted with the blank cells at the right end, or remove the blank cells from my array to begin with, but I cant seem to type out a solution that works well.

Note that this is also referencing bloomberg code to extract data from their API through
r = b.referenceData(s, f), although it do not think it is relevant for my problem.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post links.  Make sure you have embedded the images in the question.

Comment: use `union` to merge separate ranges into one, and load that final range to array. case closed. curtains ;)